# How do I make this absolute PNG file clickable?

Tags: php, click, absolute

So I am working to make a change on this site. http://www.kbduct.com . One the site there is a png file of a transparent united states logo on the front. I had to add a small awfs logo banner to it and have the viewer be able to click on it so that it can lead to a different site. I added the anchor tags to these items but nothing happens wen you click on it. Heres the index file and the external file for the image.

BTW, I didn't build this site. Im helping to maintain it for the time being.

INDEX:

```
<?php include('inc/default.php');

$pageTitle = "The Nations Source For Industrial Ducting, Ducts and Ductwork Components - KB Duct";
$pageDisc = "KB Duct is the Nation's source for industrial duct, ducting components and ductwork fittings and supplies. We offer custom built solutions for your industrial needs.";
$pageKeys = "duct, ductwork, ducting, duct work, commercial ducting, industrial ducting, custom ductwork, ductwork supplies, ducting accessories, duct fittings";

 ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<?php include('inc/head.php'); ?>

<body>



<div id="sb-site">

 <?php include('inc/maximage.php'); ?>      

 <?php include('inc/header.php'); ?>

 <div class="mainarea">

 <a href="http://awfsfair.org/">
    <div id="eBanner" style=" position: absolute; right: 380px; top: 310px;">

<?php /*?> <script type='text/javascript' src='http://libs.a2zinc.net/Common/JS/10.6.0.0/a2zWidget.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' id='exWidget'>new a2z.Widget('dGbJ%2fQfPqUA4s%2fDNrIc%2fzt5xiq%2fL4ZoFjVXmdUEcJutOcD9ggxZSCZyU8MZ6cQu6',40297,'http://libs.a2zinc.net/Common/Widgets/ExhibitorBadge.aspx',31,201133,330,200).render();</script>
<?php */?>



</a>

 </div>


    <div class="wrapper">

        <?php include('inc/industry.php'); ?>
        <?php include('inc/catatypes.php'); ?>

    <div id="mob-only">
      <?php include('inc/mobslideup.php'); ?>
    </div>

    </div>


 </div>

 <?php include('inc/footer.php'); ?>

</div>

<?php include('inc/mob-menu.php'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

MAXIMAGE.PHP:

```
<div id="maximage">
    <div>
        <img src="img/Custom-Ductwork-Clamp-Together-Ducting-Shiny-Ducts-BG.jpg" alt="KB Duct is the nation's source for clamp together and flanged industrial ducting and duct parts." />
        <div class="in-slide-content" style="display:none;">
            <a href="http://awfsfair.org/"><img src="img/nations-source-for-industrial-ducting.png" alt="KB Duct offers custom fabricated industrial ducting solutions."></a>



        </div>
    </div>
     <div>
        <img src="img/shinyduct.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="in-slide-content" style="display:none;">
            <a href="http://awfsfair.org/"><img src="img/awfs-nations-source.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div>
        <img src="img/kbduct-production.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="in-slide-content" style="display:none;">
            <img src="img/nations-source-for-industrial-ducting.png">
        </div>
    </div>-->
    <div>
        <img src="img/plasma.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="in-slide-content" style="display:none;">
            <a href="http://awfsfair.org/"><img src="img/awfs-nations-source.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="img/welding.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="in-slide-content" style="display:none;">
            <a href="http://awfsfair.org/"><img src="img/awfs-nations-source.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  <!--  <div>
        <img src="img/clamp.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="in-slide-content" style="display:none;">
            <img src="img/nations-source-for-industrial-ducting.png">
        </div>
    </div>-->
     <div>
        <img src="img/tunnel.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="in-slide-content" style="display:none;">
           <a href="http://awfsfair.org/"><img src="img/awfs-nations-source.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

MAXIMAGE CSS ID:

```
#maximage {
    display:block;/* Only use this if you fade it in again after the images load */
    position:fixed !important;
    z-index:-1;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're clicking on it? For me the link is a `0px` by `0px` element so there's no way you're gonna click on it.

Comment: Yeah, I've been clicking on it but nothings happening. Is there anything I can do to possibly fix this but still have the same result?

Comment: Should I just separate the awfs logo from the png file?